# Next.js / tRPC with WebSockets

Tags: reactjs, websocket, next.js, trpc.io

I am building an app with Next.JS and tRPC. As I need real-time communication inside my app, I want to use Websockets, which are nicely integrated into rRPC as subscriptions. (See https://trpc.io/docs/subscriptions)

In the documentation of tRPC they are creating a ws Server, however it is not documented for Next.

My questions is: How can I integrate Websocktes in this use case into Next, as I cannot find a way to run the ws Server with Next. I tried to import the file `wsServer.ts` in `_app.tsx` or in `api/trpc/[trpc].ts` without getting it to work. When doing so I always get errors of some node libraries like `fs` are not found even when ensuring that the code is run on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create [a custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) to wrap your Next.js app in order to use it.

We have a full example that is ready to deploy here: https://github.com/trpc/examples-next-prisma-starter-websockets

Beware that you can't host WebSocket servers on Vercel.

Comment: Thank you! I used this example and stripped it down to the things I need and it is working now.

Comment: Is the custom server still necessary in March 2023? There doesn't seem to be anyting mentioning custom server in the v10 doc!

Comment: Yes, you need a server to use WSS, it doesn't work on serverless

Comment: And what about server-side events? Looks like they can be used to provide ws compatible behaviour?